# `parseInt()` and `parseDouble()` throw `NumberFormatExeption`

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextfield

so I got this problem with a GUI witch has to take some info from five `JTextField`'s and put the info in an instance of a class `libro` (italian for book).

I have made some controlling if's to check if the string receved is not empty but I keep getting a `NumberFormatExeption` error in the terminal.

Code at the part the `NumberFormatExeption` happens

```
tTitle  = this.titleField.getText();
if(tTitle == null || tTitle == "")
    tTitle = "Titolo Non Conosciuto";
tAuthor  = this.authorField.getText();
if(tAuthor == null || tAuthor == "")
    tAuthor = "Autore Non Conosciuto";
tEditor = this.editorField.getText();
if(tEditor == null || tEditor == "")
    tEditor = "Editore Non Conosciuto";
tPages  = this.pagesField.getText();
if(tPages == null || tPages == "")
    tPages = "0";
tPrezzo  = this.priceField.getText();
if(tPrezzo == null || tPrezzo == "")
    tPrezzo = "0,0";
temp = new Libro(tTitle,tAuthor,tEditor,Integer.parseInt(tPages),Double.parseDouble(tPrezzo));
```

the terminal sais that the `NumberFormatExeption` is happening on the last statement in the code above. if needed here is the full error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at MyPanel.actionPerformed(MyPanel.java:148)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I don't even know exactly what `NumberFormatExeption` means. what does it mean and how can i make it not happen in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you try to parse an empty String because `tPages = "0";` is never called.

Use `tPages.isEmpty()` in your if statement instead of `tPages == ""`

Comment: That worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

When you are evaluating an object value, instead of a primitive format you will need to use operators from the object.

For `String` and other complex objects, you need to use internal methods to compare their internal values. you will need to use `tPages.equals("")`, `tPages.isEmpty()` and other values that you can see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) instead of == "", you can see more details about this [in this blog](http://blog.enrii.com/2006/03/15/java-string-equality-common-mistake/).

For your `NumberFormatException`, It's a common exception for Number object, when you create malformed numbers, once "" is not a number.

Answer (score -2):

Try 0.0 instead of 0,0. And see if it works.

Comment: the error is that he tries to parse a blank string :java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: Try this code 'Integer.parseInt("0"),Double.parseDouble("0,0")' and look if it still does that exception

Comment: @SamuelD depends on the Locale for the second case

Comment: Indeed, just wanted to see if that was his problem... Did you try debugging ?

Comment: He is trying to compare String using ==, just never do that in Java on complex objects @SamuelD.